# Undeploy all applications from Glassfish

Tags: deployment, glassfish, asadmin, undeploy

I need a way to undeploy all my applications from Glassfish. Normally, I would use `asadmin undeploy --target=[target] [appname]"` for each application. My problem is that I don't know the name of all applications that are present on the server. Is there a command that would allow me to just undeploy everything? Thanks.

Comment: perhaps easier to delete the domain and then re-create..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there isn't an 'undeploy everything' command, there is a list-applications command. This [page describes list-applications and some other commands](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24929/deploying-applications.htm#giulr) that will help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a bash script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

ASADMIN=(path to Glassfish asadmin executable)

function undeploy_all {
    for p in $*; do
        echo "Undeploying $p..."
        $ASADMIN undeploy $p
    done;
}

apps=`$ASADMIN list-applications -t | awk '{print $1;}'`

undeploy_all $apps
```

When you run it, it will undeploy all deployed applications automatically. It needs `awk`. Make sure to configure the `ASADMIN` variable with the path to `asadmin`.

Comment: Hi Johny can  you please tell me what is awk.

Comment: @ziMtyth `awk` is an interpreter for the AWK Programming Language, which is used for manipulation of data files, text retrieval and processing. Is useful for processing the output of commands, like in the script. The book for [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) is a complete reference for learning it if you are interested.